# How to find the Big O of my Happy Numbers function?

Tags: javascript, big-o

I understand that this is not the best optimized code for leetcode problem 202 Happy Number, but I am trying to figure out what the Big O of this because of the conditional while loop. Ofc if n starts out as 0-4, it would be O(1).

```
/**
 * @param {number} n
 * @return {boolean}
 */

var isHappy = function(n) {
    /* pseudocode
    - n is input
    - while loop if num is greater than 1
    - turn number to string 
    - split the string
    - map to an array
    - add all numbers' squares
    - if num is 1, break and return true
    - if not loop 
    */
    
    // check for definite false cases
    if (n === 1) {
            return true;
        }
    else if (n === 0|| n === 2 || n === 3 || n === 4) {
        return false;
        }
    
    while (n > 1) {
        // split and turn to string
        n = n.toString().split("");
        console.log(n);
        
        // map to arr
        //let tempArr = n.map(n);
        console.log("n: " + n);
        
        // add all nums squares
        let tempNum = 0;
        n.forEach(e => {
            tempNum += (e**2);
            console.log("adding ", e**2);
        });
        
        // change n to sum and reset tempNum
        n = tempNum;
        tempNum = 0;
        
        // check conditions for true/false
        if (n === 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (n === 0|| n === 2 || n === 3 || n === 4) {
        return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It should still be O(n) - constant time at 0-4 is negligible when comparing higher values for n.

Comment: Actually, this might be `O(n log_2 n)`... I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Don't be afraid to declare new variables. Re-using `n` for various types is rather confusing.

Comment: @Sfzmango Do you need more clarification on one of the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

For any integer `n > 1`, `n.toString().split("")` will have length `Math.ceil(Math.log10(n))`. Since each of `n`'s digits is less than 10, the sum of `n`'s squared digits (and the updated `n` value in the while loop after the first iteration) will be no more than `(9**2) * Math.ceil(Math.log10(n))` and will have no more than `2 + Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.ceil(Math.log10(n))))` digits. `log10(n)` is the critical contributor to the number of operations in this function. The time complexity is thus `O(log10(n))`.

Answer (score 1):

With big-O, you're trying to find the [worst-case scenario](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/big-o-notation-explained-with-examples/) - you may get lucky and hit O(1), but that won't always be the case.

Your worst case would occur when `n > 4` - the code goes to the while loop. Based on the section `n.forEach..`, your worst case is O(n).

**EDIT:**

So looking a bit more closely at the code, you cast `n` to a string and then split up the values. So in terms of the big-O notation, it depends on what we're looking at.

If we're looking at the actual value of `n` (for example, 30, 100, 10,000), then it's O(log(n)), since log(100) = 2, and 3 operations would occur in your `n.foreach`.

If we're looking at the number of digits in `n` (100 has 3 digits), then it's log(n).

Comment: I don't think it's O(n). The value of n changes with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Based on OP's code, I don't think it will - the only thing that gets updated in the `forEach` block is the variable `tempNum`. `n` will remain unchanged until after the loop where they run `n = tempNum;`

Comment: Actually, I think you're right - this isn't O(n). What get's weird is when they cast to a string then split - then `n` is based on how every many digits it has - ie - n = 100 would run the for loop 3 times, 1000 would run the loop 4 times, etc... I actually don't know what O() would be in this case

Comment: Yeah, the re-assignment of `n` at the beginning of the loop is confusing.

Comment: Okay, it depends on your definition of `n` for the log notation. If it's the value of n (for example, 23, 100, 10,000), then it's technically O(log(n)) since you split the numbers (100 would give 3 operations, log(100) = 2, so pretty close to log(n). If instead `n` is defined as the number of digits in the value (100 would be 3), then it's log(n). Casting to the string just makes it super wonky.